# Inno Setup compile directory

Tags: java, ant, inno-setup

This is the first time I've used Inno Setup. I am including Inno Setup in an ANT script:

```
<target name="generate-installer-exe" depends="generate-exe">
  <exec executable="C:/Program Files (x86)/Inno Setup 5/ISCC.exe">
    <arg value="${etc.dir}/innoSetup_config.iss"/>
    <arg value="/dMySourcePath=${deployment.dir}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

It creates the Output and setup.exe in the `${etc.dir}` since that is where my .iss file is, but i want it to compile to the `${deployment.dir}`.  Is there anyway to dynamically change the compile directory by passing an argument or do I need to move the files via ANT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, the /O parameter can do what you need.

> "/O" to specify an output path (overriding any OutputDir setting in
>   the script), "/F" to specify an output filename (overriding any
>   OutputBaseFilename setting in the script)

So, if you want to just pass the /O for an output directory, you would probably need something like:

```
<target name="generate-installer-exe" depends="generate-exe">
  <exec executable="C:/Program Files (x86)/Inno Setup 5/ISCC.exe">
    <arg value="${etc.dir}/innoSetup_config.iss"/>
    <arg value="/dMySourcePath=${deployment.dir}"/>
    <arg value="/O${deployment.dir}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```